# Google transliteration API in Java Swing project

Tags: java, swing, api, transliteration

I'm working on a transliteration project in Java Swing. It can access the internet, but I'm unable to set it up. How do we do that? Do we need to download the Google API libraries or just a function call will do?

Here are some useful Transliteration links:

[*The Google Transliterate API Devloper's Guide*](http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/v1/getting_started.html#introduction)

[*Google API library for Java for download*](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

(I think it has all API libraries of Google:Translate, transliterate, search, etc.)

I spent a lot of time, but Icouldn't find how to set up the Transliteration API, not even at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the transliteration API is deprecated and is not included in the Java client, only in the JavaScript client.

The actual calls the JS library makes are pretty simple and could easily be replicated from anywhere:

```
http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?ime=transliteration_en_ru&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&text=prosto
```

Don't know if doing that is against Google's terms, though. Probably it is.

You could also try running the Ajax client in [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). You'll need [env-js](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js#readme) which provides a pure javascript DOM environment.

It's just hideous enough to work!

Comment: How do I do the Google transliteration from within my swing application. Please can you make this simple for me, by explaining the details. Also is there any other method for Google transliteration without using Rhino

Comment: The simplest way is to call their REST api directly, like in the example above.  Just set the `ime` and `text` parameters to your input (to select the languages and set the text to transliterate), make the call with HttpUrlConnection (or any other java HTTP client) and parse the JSON string it returns. I was half joking about the Rhino thing - it would work, but is a ridiculously complicated way of doing it.